# IRegion.ActivateView doesn't show the View in an XBAP application

Tags: wpf, mvvm, unity-container, prism-4

I have a WPF Windows application that I developed using Prism/Unity framework.

Now I want to convert it to XBAP application as well so it can be hosted in the IIS and can be shared on the network.

I have one Main view (Shell.xaml) that is derived from Windows and rest of the views are UserControls. I have converted the Shell.xaml to be derived from Page Class.

Everything works well and there is no error as such but the first view (which is login view should be displayed on the Shell's region) is not getting displayed. I tried to debug the application and saw that IRegion.ActivateView is getting called properly but some how the view is not getting displayed onto UI.

Can any one tell me why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Sharad Rastogi